# Debriefing participants right away or later in an online study

Tags: research-process, ethics

I am curious about this question related to ethics. Within my own *online* study (by the standard code of ethics), it is needed to review participants after the study. However, I am wondering whether it *has to be done* right away *or* for example *within 3 days* of completing the initial study. I see pros and cons of either.

For example if I consider it from the viewpoint of giving the debrief right away, then

pros are:

- Participants can ask questions more easily as they remember more
- Higher likelihood of being interested in the debrief

cons are:

- Researchers cannot check whether any potential problems (e.g. errors, software malfunction) arose during the procedure and if it would be required to repeat the procedure.
- Respondent cognitive fatigue

It would be nice to hear examples of how you would deal with it.

Comment: I don't think this is a question of ethics, there is nothing morally wrong either way, but of study methodology, and I think the answer depends on many specific factors: how likely is that you can get hold of your subjects after a few days, how long and tiring the experiment is, how feasible is to have _both_ options...